# How can i remove an elements from Arraylist without using clear() or whatever methods?

Tags: java, eclipse, arraylist

I've tried writing code that removes all elements in Arraylist without using a clear() , and remove() . or whatever from class ArrayList

look to my code :

```
for (int i=0 ; i<a.size(); i++) 
                    a.get(i) =null ;
```

but i have an error :

The left-hand side of an assignment must be a variable

any ideas ?

Comment: Even if Java had an indexer syntax, what you are suggesting would just set `null` at that list position. That's not the same as "removing".

Comment: If a list has a `clear` method, that's for a reason. Take the class as it is and use its methods, or don't use the class at all

Answer (score 1):

a.get() will return a **value not a reference-holder** i.e. left-hand operand of "=" operator should be some variable which can hold the result given by the right-hand expression of the equals operator.

Internally ArrayList will have every element in its implementation, and without using Collection's Arraylist API, that is either `remove()` or `clear()` you will be not able to delete any of its items.

Comment: What difference do you make between *value* and *variable* ? I think you meant a pointer or something like that

Comment: Yes. Left hand side of an equal operator must be a variable or reference holder.

Comment: @Dici but still if we use this `a.set(i, null)`, the arrayList size will not vary, because the array will replace original value with null value.

Comment: I know, I was just pointing out the mistake in the vocabulary. The answer is otherwise correct

Comment: Yeah, I got that. Thanks.(y)

Answer (score 1):

First of all, setting it to null will not remove the element. Instead, it will just set it to an element with value null.

If you want to remove the element, you **should** use remove. Or clear, for all of them.

If you wish to set them as null, use `a.set(i, null)`

Comment: FYI: but still if we use `a.set(i, null)`, the arrayList size will not vary, because the array will replace original value with null value.

Comment: Hence the qualifier "If you wish to set them as null", as a follow up to the first paragraph and an alternative to the second (which is the case of wanting to remove elements). I was clear about this in my answer.